# Multer returns `undefined` for file uploads with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, filereader, form-data

Regardless of how I implement the file upload I get an `undefined` returned when inspecting the `req.file` property of the request in Express.

..

**React Code**

Component:

```
import Files from 'react-files';

<form encType="multipart/formdata">
     <Files
        ref='files'
        onChange={this.onFileUpload}>
     </Files>
</form>
```

Method:

```
onFileUpload (files) {

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = upload => {
        this.setState({
            dataURI: upload.target.result
        }, () => {

            if (typeof appState.balance == 'number' && appState.balance > 0) {
                appState.onFileAdd(files, this.state.dataURI);

            } else {
                this.setState({ modal: true });
            }

        });
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[files.length - 1]);
}
```

This works correctly; the `dataURI` value in the state is legitimate and set correctly.

..

**API Call Code**

```
export async function funFile(name, dataURI) {
   let data = new FormData();

   data.append('file', dataURI);
   data.append('name', name);

   return await fetch('http://localhost:1185/fun',
    { method: 'POST', data }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok && res.status == 200) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Inspecting `data` here returns the expected `FormData` object, though without the ability to see the assigned `name` and `file` attributes (whether this is because they are not assigned correctly or this is expected behaviour I'm not sure).

..

**Express Code**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ destination: 'uploads/' });

app.post('/fun', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {

   console.log('file', req.file);
   console.log('files', req.files);

   // both of these return undefined
});
```

Regardless of what I do at this point, the request returns no file data. The `req.body` property is also empty.

I'm not sure exactly where things have gone wrong here, and from all possible tutorials and walkthroughs on this implementation I have tried all possible syntactical permutations I can think of, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: what does your `upload.single('file')` does ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with reading the file as data url. Forget about the `FileReader`. You do not need to read anything, just pass a file object to your `FormData` and you should be all set.

**onChange**

```
onFileUpload (files) {

  this.setState({
    file: files[files.length-1]
  }, () => {

    if (typeof appState.balance == 'number' && appState.balance > 0) {
      appState.onFileAdd(files, this.state.file);
    } else {
      this.setState({ modal: true });
    }

  });
}
```

**API Call**

```
export async function funFile(name, file) {
   let data = new FormData();

   data.append(name, file); // name here should be avatar

   return await fetch('http://localhost:1185/fun',
    { method: 'POST', data }).then(res => {
        if (res.ok && res.status == 200) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```